# saving day wise logs in Azure App Service for Django Application

Tags: django, azure, logging, django-rest-framework, azure-web-app-service

Below is the logging format I have for a DRF application in azure app service. I tried using Timed Rotating File handler but I was not able to save the logs with that option. Also, when ever the app service restarts, the previous logs are getting erased. Is there a way to maintain day wise logs in azure app service.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
    },  
    'filters':{
        'error_mails': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.CallbackFilter',
            'callback':'app.log.CustomExceptionReporter'
        },
        'require_debug_false': {
              '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
           },
    },                                                                
    'handlers': {
        'logfile': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': f'{BASE_DIR}/app_log.log',
            'maxBytes': 9000000,
            'backupCount': 10,
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
        'console':{
            'level':'INFO',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'include_html' :True,
            'reporter_class':'app.log.CustomExceptionReporter',
            # 'filters':['require_debug_false',]
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['logfile','mail_admins'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'ERROR',
        },
         'django.request':{
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },        
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'app': {
            'handlers': ['logfile','console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propogate': True,
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to maintain day-wise logs in the azure app service.

Currently, it is **not possible** to save a log day-wise.  By default, **App Service** the log will be saved in `LogFiles\Application\`. And we were not able to change the **log file name** also.

#### Application logging

- **File System** -   Save the logs into the  **filesystem**. This setting          will only stay enabled for  **12 hours**
- **Azure Blob Storage**-   You can also save the logs to  **Azure Blob Storage**, even if you also save the logs to the file system(This feature is not available for Linux App service)

You can also define a level of **verbosity** for the application logging to catch. This allows you to filter logging data into **Error**, **Warning**, **Information**, or **Verbose** categories. All information that you log will be caught by the Verbose value. Refer [Azure App Service Log files](https://stackify.com/azure-app-service-log-files/).

> whenever the app service restarts, the previous logs are getting erased

You have to take a backup of your App so that we can get all information (Configuration, log files, App details) about App Service. Refer [App Service Backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-backup)